# execute bash commands in a c file and store the output in an array

Tags: c, operating-system

I'm trying to store the number of page faults into an array in my c program. I want to execute bash command and store the output of it in an array.
here's my command

```
$ cat /proc/vmstat | grep pgfault
```

Comment: `popen()` plus `fread()`.

Comment: Include that line in your C program that creates an array and then prepares to store the data within a loop.

Answer (score 1):

A simple start, can be embellished and improved...

```
char * lines[2000];         /* 2000 lines enough? */
int    n = 0;

FILE * fp = popen("your command here", "r");
if (fp == NULL) abort();

lines[0] = malloc(1000);    /* 1000 byte lines enough? */
while ((fgets(lines[n], 1000, fp) != NULL) {
    if (n == 1999) abort();       /* oh crud... */
    lines[++n] = malloc(1000);
}
free(lines[n]);
pclose(fp);
/* do something with lines[0 .. n-1] here */
/* then free them */
```

Comment: It sure can be embellished, perhaps by avoiding leaking 1999 lines (in the worst case).